# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-axis, portal, zk

I am developing a web portal using tomcat 7 + ZK framework + axis2 for using web services. After a while I started getting this error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet /twigo threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Maybe axis2 1.6 isn't compatible with tomcat 7 ?

Answer (score 7):

This is a strange problem, even after adding all the jars of Apache Axis2 annoying exception is still there. Required class **AxisAdminServlet** is not present in Axis2 libs(1.6.1 in my case). Since its nomore there in framework itself i guess its no longer required, so i removed it from my code.

You can get rid of this inside web.xml where call is placed for the servlet.

[image: web.xml snapshot]

Comment: Just in case if someone needs to have AxisAdminServlet, you can build a jar file from axis2-1.x.x\webapp\WEB-INF, it contains the required servlet

Answer (score 5):

There may be below entry in the web.xml

```
<display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

If so, please remove this entry from web.xml which solves the problem.

Regards,
Kishore

Answer (score 2):

There are differences from axis2 different releases!
In the axis2 v1.8.0 the web.xml files contains these rows:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The axis2 libraries must contains those packages/classes shown at tag **servlet-class**